# Error message: no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to determine the width at half height of a density plot, and I found the following code in a previous post:

```
  d <- ggplot(A0, aes(DIAMETER)) +
  geom_density()

xmax <- d$x[d$y==max(d$y, na.rm = TRUE)]
x1 <- d$x[d$x < xmax][which.min(abs(d$y[d$x < xmax]-max(d$y)/2))]
x2 <- d$x[d$x > xmax][which.min(abs(d$y[d$x > xmax]-max(d$y)/2))]
FWHM <- x2-x1
```

when I execute it though I get the following error message relative to the function max()

```
Warning message:
In max(d$y, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I looked a bit around and saw that this could be due to the presence of NA value in my dataset but that is not the case (structure of data frame below).. does someone know how I could fix this problem ? thanks in advance!

```
str(A0)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   387 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ SAMPLE  : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TIME    : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","24","72": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DIAMETER: num  13.57 3.76 10.67 14.74 4.2 ...
```

Comment: compare to `max(c(NA, NA), na.rm=TRUE)` What is `d$y`? Please show the data of `d$y` in your question.

Comment: d$y is the y axis on the density plot d ... I am actually not sure thet is the best way to calculate the width at half height in the first place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're possibly misinterpreting the code you found. A `ggplot` object simply doesn't have a member called `y`. Suppose we make a density plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)
d <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = rnorm(100)), aes(x)) + geom_density()
d
```

[image]

We can replicate your error like this:

```
xmax <- d$x[d$y==max(d$y, na.rm = TRUE)]
#> Warning message:
#> In max(d$y, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

And if we try to look at `d$y` we get:

```
d$y
#> NULL
```

If you want to work with the underlying data from a plot you need to use `ggbuild`, like this:

```
p <- ggplot_build(d)
```

Now `p` contains a list of data frames, one for each plot layer, so in our case we can do:

```
df <- p$data[[1]]
```

Now `df` is a data frame containing our `x` and `y` coordinates, so we can run your algorithm

```
xmax <- df$x[df$y==max(df$y, na.rm = TRUE)]
x1 <- df$x[df$x < xmax][which.min(abs(df$y[df$x < xmax]-max(df$y)/2))]
x2 <- df$x[df$x > xmax][which.min(abs(df$y[df$x > xmax]-max(df$y)/2))]
FWHM <- x2-x1

FWHM
#> [1] 2.100466
```

and we can see this calculation is correct by plotting a segment between the x1 and x2 values at half the maximum height:

```
 d + geom_segment(aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = max(df$y)/2, yend = max(df$y)/2), 
                  linetype = 2, colour = "red")
```

[image]